# Hide navigation until all items are populated

Tags: 2010, jquery, navigation, css

I created a customized nav using the Sharepoint aspmenu with simple rendering which binds to an xml datasource to render the menu contents.

I am then using a the jquery UI accordion to style it.

The problem is that sometimes if the page is loading slowly it shows the fully expended (simple rendered view) before the page has chance to load and apply the jquery/css styles against it.

I don't want to write code to lazy load it but was thinking maybe I could just not show the menu until I know for sure that all the css and javascript has been loaded and the style applied. I just can't think of the best way to tackle this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already working on it with jQuery then set it to hidden by default then change to show after you have applied the accordion.